# Gitlab runner cannot deploy to kubernetes cluster

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

My problem is similar to [Deploying to Kubernetes cluster using runner from GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148037/deploying-to-kubernetes-cluster-using-runner-from-gitlab) but it didn't get a solution unfortunately.

I have a gitlab pipeline job that deploys to an AKS cluster called . This pipeline executes on a gitlab runner that is helm deployed on a different kubernetes cluster called .

The gitlab agent is successfully deployed using helm chart on cluster  while the runner is successfully deployed on cluster .

However, the runner is currently unable to deploy to the  cluster due to possible permission issues. I have created serviceaccounts but somehow the deployment keeps using the default serviceaccount created when the namespace was created.

ERROR From pipeline:

```
 helm upgrade "test-${ENVIRONMENT}" ./helloworld-chart --install -n $NAMESPACE -f "./helloworld-chart/values.yaml"
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /builds/test-deploy-agent-ci.tmp/KUBECONFIG
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /builds/test-deploy-agent-ci.tmp/KUBECONFIG
***Error: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:test-runner:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"***
```

Question:
How do I give the gitlab runner on a different Cluster access to run a deployment on a different cluster that has the gitlab agent also running?

NOTE: I created a service account, generated the secret and generated a config.toml file. According to some googling, I am supposed to pass this config file to the runner during helm deployment but no idea how to do this?

Will appreciate any leads on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. The deployment process is handled by the gitlab agent which runs as a container on the target k8s cluster. **Solution was to use the agent context.**

I added **"kubectl config get-contexts"** to my pipeline  script to determine what cluster i am connected to and interestingly, I was not seeing the runners clusters but that of the agent on gitlab.

Here is an example from pipeline execution log:

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                           CLUSTER   AUTHINFO      NAMESPACE
          poc-primary-agent   gitlab    agent:0000
```

So within your .gitlab-ci.yml, be sure to do this:

```
kubectl config use-context poc-primary-agent
```